# What size should be used for fgets?

Tags: c, string, styles, fgets, code-readability

I have the following segment of code in one of my programs:

```
char input[LINE_SIZE + 1]; /* +1 for '\0'. */

while(fgets(input, LINE_SIZE, stdin) != NULL)
{
    /* Do stuff. */
}
```

In a question that has since been deleted, it was pointed out to me that my code could potentially be buggy. I declare strings with the "+ 1" notation to make the code more informative and readable (ensuring that I do not forget to account for the NULL terminator, because this used to be an issue). However, I have been told that the `fgets` should use the exact same size for its second parameter. I have seen other posts here that do the same practices as me.

I am unsure. Is it bad practice to not include the "+ 1" in the fgets parameter as well?

Comment: The plus/minus 1 is not needed.  Suggest `fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin)` when `input` is an array.

Comment: Why pass a value which you *know* is off by 1? Having said that, it is off by 1 in the safe direction, so poses little actual risk.

Comment: for `char input[LINE_SIZE + 1];`, `LINE_SIZE` is the maximum number of characters (not counting the terminator), and `LINE_SIZE + 1` is the actual size of the array.  For `fgets()`, you pass the size of the array... it'll read at most one less character than that, and add the terminator.

Comment: @JohnColeman You just said the exact reason... having it off by 1 in the safe direction ensures that if you accidentally are off by 1 in the unsafe direction they just cancel out. For instance some functions take a length that does not include the string terminator.

Comment: I had the notion that `fgets` didn't account for the '\0'. I had seen many people doing this on StackOverflow and I have checked out some manpages to see this question but it was not answered there.

Comment: Dmitri has the right idea. It's worth mentioning that I _intend_ to not have wasted space in my array `input`. Will my method for `fgets` put in at most `LINE_SIZE` non-NULL characters into `input`, or will it put `LINE_SIZE` characters _including_ the NULL terminator?

Comment: from the docs: `fgets()` reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by size... If any characters are read and there is no error, a `\0' character is appended to end the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **7.21.7.2 The `fgets` function**
> Synopsis
> 1        `#include <stdio.h>`
>          `char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n, FILE * restrict stream);`
> Description
> 2     The `fgets` function reads **at most one less than the number of characters specified by `n`**
> from the stream pointed to by `stream` into the array pointed to by `s`. No additional
> characters are read after a new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file. A
> null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array.

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

Emphasis added.

If you specify `LINE_SIZE`, then `fgets` will read *at most* `LINE_SIZE - 1` characters into `input`, and will write a 0 terminator following the last input character.  Note that `fgets` will store the newline character if there's room.

Comment: This explained the question greatly. Thank you. I will have to change all occurences of `fgets` using `LINE_SIZE` to `LINE_SIZE + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment (<50 points) but:

if you use

```
char input[LINE_SIZE ];

while(fgets(input, LINE_SIZE, stdin) != NULL)
{
    /* Do stuff. */
}
```

fgets() will not write beyond your input[] buffer, however if you actually needed LINE_SIZE characters captured, you'll receive that last character by itself in the next call, which you might not expect.

also: the sizeof keyword will not return the full size of run-time allocations, so you'll have to keep track of which buffers are dynamically allocated and use a different method:

```
char * input = malloc(50)    
fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin)
```

> reads 8 (LP64) characters